# Access Background image in phones via USB connection

Tags: android, wpd, mtp

I'm developing a PC c++ application running on windows. The application shall communicate with a phone connected thru USB, using MTP. I want to specifically access the background image in phone. Is there a way to do so? Is there a specific way to access background image in Android devices?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist && http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There's a fairly high chance that the same image (or original copy therefor) being used as a background would be available via MTP, but it's not clear that you'd have anything available through MTP which you could query to find out which one it is.

Comment: thanks for the help Chris.. Can we at least access device icon for the device via MTP?